# Biber/BibTex: citing online sources in footnote without / in bibliography with URL

Tags: biblatex, biber, urls

I am usually using `biber` in combination with the brilliant `biblatex-dw` style to write books.

This time, the publisher asks me to not include any URL's in footnotes and replace these by the term "online resource". Ok, I can do that and understand that footnotes with long URL are not exactly pretty - I would like to include the URL's in the bibliography section though. Does anyone have an idea how to replace URL's in the footnotes by "online resource", but print them full in the bibliography?

The only solution I can think of now is making two .bib entries (`source-with-onlineresource`, `source-with-url`), one with the keyword `nourl`, then always cite with a double entry with `\cite{source-with-onlineresource}\nocite{source-with-url}` and then print the bibliography with `\printbibliography[notkeyword={nourl}]`.

Does anyone have an idea for a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) to your question (see also [MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)). That way we have something to play round with and can check if our suggested solutions work with your setup. It will also help us on a few detail questions. You mention you use `biblatex-dw` but which of the styles do you actually use: `footnote-dw` or `authoryear-dw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `footnote-dw` it should be enough to redefine the `url+urldate` macro to just print 'online rescource' in citations. That can be done with

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \usebibmacro{footref}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{\iffieldundef{url}{}{\printtext{online resource}}}%
       \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}%
    \iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {}
      {\ifbool{cbx:citedas}
        {\addspace\usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
        {}}}}
```

Where we only added the line `\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{\iffieldundef{url}{}{\printtext{online resource}}}`.

Alternatively, you could change the logic slightly to only show the 'online rescource' message if you have an `@online` entry with a URL:

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{\ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{url}} and test {\ifentrytype{online}}}{\printtext{online resource}}{}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked! For some reason I had to comment out "\usebibmacro{footref}"